# Adding two functions / multiplying two functions yields wrong answer python

Tags: python, function, addition

I've made a simple example to try and add two functions (for now, want multiply in the end but neither of them work so I decided to try adding).

```
def addFun(fun1,fun2):
    fun = lambda x: fun1(x) + fun2(x)
    return fun
d = [12,10]
B = 5
fun1 = lambda d,L: (d-L)**2

result1 = lambda L: 0
for i in range(0,len(d)):
    func = lambda L: fun1(float(d[i]),L)
    result1 = addFun(result1,func)
    print(func(1))

print(result1(1))
```

The print functions are there to check whether it's working or not (so far it's not. So ideally what should happen is (d-L)^2 for d = 12 is (12-L)^2. I add that to result1 which is now (12-L)^2. Then on the next loop it becomes (10-L)^2. Now the addFun function should add these two together, so the new result1 should be
    (12-L)^2 + (10-L)^2. Then I substitute L as 1, answer should be 11^2 + 9^2 = 202. However this is not the case. When I run this through, the resulting answer is 162. Worst thing is the + sign doesn't commute; when I put in 10 first and 12 second, the answer becomes 242.

I've had this working for simpler equations, such as adding x^2 with x^3 e.t.c. But does anyone know why this isn't working here?

Comment: don't dox lambda functions

Comment: @wim why not? What's wrong with doing that in python

Comment: `d` and `i` are being looked up *by name* in your `func` lambda - when you finally execute the whole thing at the end, all of the individual lambdas will see the *same* value of `i`, the one it had in the final iteration of the loop.  Usual solution is to write it as `lambda L, i=i:` so that you capture the current value of `i` as a default parameter.

Comment: @jasonharper Yeah thats worked thank you very much!